# Widget disappears after wrapping with Center in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is my widget tree, [image]

Before adding center, [image]

After adding center, [image]

My code showing the SignInButton and other things in tree to reproduce the issue.,

```dart
class SignInButton extends StatelessWidget {
  SignInButton({Key? key, required this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  final void Function() onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon: Image(
          image: AssetImage("assets/images/google.png"),
          color: null,
          height: 20,
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white, onPrimary: Colors.black),
        label: Text("Sign in with Google"));
  }
}


Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  body: Center(
    child: Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      spacing: 5,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Text(
            'Text',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.orange.shade400,
              fontSize: 26,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Center(
            child: SignInButton(onPressed: () async {
              User? user =
                  await Authentication.signInWithGoogle(context: context);

              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: ((context) => SignUpScreen())));
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

After adding code of Center widget, the sign in button just disappears. I am not sure why this is happening, it is available in tree of Flutter Inspector.

Comment: Can you include a sample full snippet that will reproduce the issue, like here missing `SignInButton`

Comment: could you please add parent of your SizedBox() and SignInButton() too?

Comment: I have added the whole code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is no bound in height axis. Please try to define some value to height, in SizedBox or inside SignInButton.

Comment: It worked after giving the sizedBox a height, can you tell the reason for why the problem occurred ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's because the Wrap widget(layout horizontal) needs to calculate his own height based on sum of all children height after they are allocated and rendered

P.S. `Center` do not define child height, so there is no constrains